# QT - Select section of image

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using QLabel and QPixmap to show image in my program. I would like to use something like snipping tool in Windows to let user to select part of image that will be processed further.

For example, I load image, user select part of it (rectangle), and it shows it is selected and I can read coordinates that are selected, so I can proceed with processing only part of image.

Comment: Please, add a specific question. Please, show a [mcve] to expose what you (already) have and what does not work as expected.

Comment: I think it's not too hard to implement. You simply need to draw a rectangle (selection) over your pixmap. The coordinates of that rectangle are: upper left corner (point where mouse button pressed) and lower right corner (where mouse button released). Of course this depends also in which direction mouse was dragged.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible with Qt without a fair amount of coding.

Maybe a third-party Qt widget, such as https://github.com/dimkanovikov/ImageCropper, is what you're looking for?